# Mercurial unbundle error: abort: ... unknown bundle version 20

Tags: linux, version-control, mercurial

I'm on linux ubuntu 14.04 lts and I use Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.3.2). I try to unbundle a mercurial hg bundle made on Mac osx with command line:

---

*hg unbundle  XXX.hg*

*abort: XXX.hg: unknown bundle version 20*

---

Does anyone have a clue what is going on? Google research has not been providing much informations about that.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add `type='bzip2-v1'` to the bundle call

```
from mercurial.commands import bundle
bundle(ui, repo, tmpfile.name, dest=None, base=(parentc.rev(),), rev=(c.rev(),), type='bzip2-v1')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mercurial introduced a new version of their bundle module somewhere around 3.2, according to:

https://hglabhq.com/blog/2014/4/29/what-s-new-in-mercurial-3-0

Your version should have support for bundle2, but there may be some problems unbundling from newer versions of mercurial.

Comment: There is no command `unbundle2`. Try `hg --config experimental.bundle2-exp=True unbundle` to enable bundle2 support in older versions. Bundle2 support was enabled in 3.5 by default, 3.3.2 may still be missing it even when unpacking.